Polymorphic DI framework or setup for .NET?
The situation that I have is the following and albeit quite simple, it seems not to be supported (at least out of the box) for 2 DI frameworks that I tried.
public interface IPlugin
{
    // misc
}

public class ConcretePlugin : IPlugin //more interfaces follow
{
    //implementation
}

class TestConcrete
{
    private ConcretePlugin plugin;

    public TestConcrete(ConcretePlugin plugin)
    {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
}

class TestList
{
    private IEnumerable<IPlugin> plugins;

    public TestList(IEnumerable<IPlugin> plugins)
    {
        this.plugins = plugins;
    }
}

Below I am trying to compose the objects as follows:
//literally, using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

ServiceCollection sc = new();
sc.AddSingleton(new ConcretePlugin(/*some arguments here*/)); // [1]
sc.AddSingleton<TestConcrete>();
sc.AddSingleton<TestList>();
ServiceProvider provider = sc.BuildServiceProvider();
provider.GetService<TestList>();

The above calls the TestList constructor with an empty IEnumerable. If I change [1] to sc.AddSingleton<IPlugin>(new ConcretePlugin(/*some arguments here*/)); then TestConcrete can't be instantiated.
I could register for every super type:
var plugin = new ConcretePlugin(/*some arguments here*/);
sc.AddSingleton<ConcretePlugin>(plugin);
sc.AddSingleton<IPlugin>(plugin);
...

But it defeats the purpose of using a DI framework and also I have multiple interfaces implemented that I want to inject in different collections. That's cumbersome and I'd like to avoid it as every time I add an interface implementation I'll have to remember to register it to the DI.
It seems quite a straightforward use case to me. I'd guess I'm missing some configuration? Note that I tried the same setup with Simple Injector but the result was the same.
Addendum
Apparently this question created a lot of confusion and I will try to address most of the issues. That's a pity given the fact that the concept is dead simple -IMHO.
First of all let's see "why" and let's examine the following example:
var plugin = new ConcretePlugin(/*some arguments here*/);
var new TestConcrete(plugin);
var new TestInterface(plugin); // accepts only a single IPlugin for simplicity

In the above example of pure DI, I don't have to explicitly tell the type system that plugin is of type IPlugin. var new TestList((IPlugin)plugin); is redundant.
If I try the same thing with a DI framework, I find myself having the following imaginary (and simplified) dialog with system:
- Register an instance of ConcretePlugin.
- Duly received.
- Now register a TestConcrete, resolve the arguments.
- Done as well.
- Now register a TestInterface, resolve the arguments.
- Sorry, can't do: there is no instance of IPlugin to use.

But the instance is there. DI frameworks were meant to help us doing DI, not change the way we reason with it. The above example of pure DI is a valid example of polymorphism, hence the tag (that I had to reintroduce BTW).

Yes but how should it work?

Well that's something that should be black-boxed, but in any case there are possible solutions. I'd expect the DI framework to lazily look if any of the registrations are subtypes of a requested unregistered type. "But that will have a performance impact" I hear you already protesting. Granted, I'm willing to measure and possibly pay the toll. By being lazy the container avoids registration of every parent interface or class.

what would happen if TestList implemented IList<Something>

I guess that what Panagiotis means here is that TestList could implement IPlugin and create a circular reference. Well the solution is simple: you can't pass the object to itself. TestList cantDoThis = new (new IPluginp[] { cantDoThis } ); is wrong - besides being pointless. Why should it be considered when using DI?

The approach I have used is to add extension methods to provide special functionality. You could make a AddSingletonAndAllSuperTypes<T> that uses reflection to register all the interfaces. Or some overloads that add the concrete type and one or more specified interfaces all at once.

Thanks @JonasH, I will consider it if everything else fails.

Do note that, when it comes to working Microsoft's built-in DI framework MS.DI, it contains very little features out of the box. What you are looking for is a form of Auto-Registration where multiple types (or, in your case, one type with multiple interfaces) can be registered in one single call. Auto-Registration relies heavily on the use of Reflection. MS.DI, however, almost completely lacks this feature, which means that you almost always have to write this extra Reflection yourself -or- need to pull in a third-party library to do the job for you.

What you ask can be a serious problem - what would happen if TestList implemented IList<Something>? Or IEquatable ? Just because there's an interface doesn't mean that all types that implement it should register it.

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. :( I updated the question, please let me know if I took something wrong. I also mention lazy lookup in order to avoid exactly that, the "pre-emptive" registration of all super types.

@Steven noted, I'm not interested to make MS.DI work; I'd be happy either by finding a DI framework that has that feature, or make one of the ones mentioned work. So far, the closest one was Autofac's .AsImplementedInterfaces() that you mentioned in another comment.

I can suggest registering only ConcretePlugin, then use it to resolve eveything that might depend on it.
For example:
sc.AddSingleton<ConcretePlugin>();
// Resolve IPlugin using already registered instance.
sc.AddSingleton<IPlugin>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<ConcretePlugin>());

Update
In order to register type as itself and as interface implementation for each implemented interface (and return one single object all the time), you can use such method:
public static class ServiceExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddTypeAsItselfAndInterfaces<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
        where T : class
    {
        var implementedInterfaces = typeof(T).GetInterfaces();
        services.AddSingleton<T>();
        foreach (var implementedInterface in implementedInterfaces)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(implementedInterface, sp => sp.GetRequiredService(typeof(T)));
        }
        return services;
    }
}


Thanks for the answer but that isn't very different from what I suggested. :) I'll have to do that for every interface that ConcretePlugin implements and I'd like to avoid that.

@SteliosAdamantidis Even if there was a way to automate, what would be the logic? Register ConcretePlugin for every interface? Or register any type for any interace it implements and itself? Heads up, there's none out of the box tool doing that, but maybe i can help with implementing something custom.

How it would be implemented sounds like an implementation detail to me that a good library should normally hide from its users. ;) I'll see if I can add an addendum later on with more details.

@SteliosAdamantidis I am asking about details, as there is no library... I ahve added some example how you can achieve (what i guess) you want.

I understand! But that's still a work-around. The answer effectively is "oh you can use reflection". Thanks, I know I can. :) I'd like something supported by the framework so allow me to wait for other suggestions.

I think the DI Container Autofac has what you are looking for. It contains an AsImplementedInterfaces() and .AsSelf() helper methods to register a type by both its concrete type and all the interfaces it implements.

@SteliosAdamantidis Autofac uses relfection too. Any DI library that auto-registers uses reflection or compiler-generated information, eg using source generators or whatever Spring uses. Checking whether a type implements certain interfaces at runtime is reflection.

@PanagiotisKanavos I didn't argue that I don't want reflection at all. I'm not naïve.  :) What I'm arguing is that I know how to do that myself, there wasn't any reason to ask in SO. I'd just like the DI framework to support it. Really, I think that what I'm asking for is quite simple, I can't understand why it has created so much confusion.

@MichałTurczyn question updated, I hope it addresses all of your questions.

@MichałTurczyn already gave the answer for MS.DI, so I won't repeat that. Here's how to do it with Simple Injector:
var container = new Container();

var concrete = new ConcretePlugin(/*some arguments here*/);
container.Collection.AppendInstance<IPlugin>(concrete);
container.RegisterInstance(concrete);
container.Register<TestConcrete>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.Register<TestList>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

container.GetInstance<TestList>();


Thank you for the answer Steven, but I specifically mentioned in my question that I'd like to avoid multiple registrations of the same object. And BTW thanks for fixing the rename that I missed.

This is not something that Simple Injector supports out of the box. Just like @MichałTurczyn mentioned for MS.DI, with Simple Injector you will have to do write a helper method that does this using reflection.

I must say though, that your use case (having a manually created object - rather than an object created by the container using Auto-Wiring - with that many interfaces that manually registering the interfaces less maintainable) is not something I ever needed in the applications I write and maintain. Because this use case is (in my opinion) so uncommon, that I deliberately left this out of Simple Injector. This follows one of the core design principles behind Simple Injector, which is to make simple use cases easy, and to make complex use cases possible.

I haven't worked on that many projects to have an opinion. In Spring DI that I'm using, this is a no-brainer. I know as I did it for work a few weeks ago. But Spring DI is of completely different philosophy. Regarding the why, I think implementing interfaces is a nice way to give capabilities to a type. Then I want to process all objects with the same capability. If you are interested to have this in your project, I can investigate if it's feasible. But I can't know what is the direction that you want to take with Simple Injector and if such a feature coincides with your goals. :)

@SteliosAdamantidis, I'm not arguing the need for to have classes implement multiple interfaces. My experience is that you'll often end up doing this to adhere to the Interface Segregation Principle and Single Responsibility Principle. All the applications I write contain classes that implement multiple interfaces. However, I have yet to come across your specific situation, where the type can't be registered using Auto-Registration and where having multiple registrations for such type (one per interface) results in maintenance issues.

@SteliosAdamantidis Spring DI is of completely different philosophy exactly - and one that's considered pretty heavyweight by today's standards, closer to old-style J2EE than Dependency Injection. Microsoft actually made the mistake of creating an everything-and-the-kitchen-sink DI back in the Enterprise Library days, that was overcomplicated and everyone hated. Trying to register every interface would cause serious problems, eg imagine registering a service as an IList<Something> implementation just because it implements that interface

Autofac supports what I think you're looking to do, but before I explain the answer, let me explain why I think you might be asking the wrong question.
Autofac, and the majority (maybe all?) of the .NET DI frameworks are built on the notion of separating the concepts of...

Component: This is the class that you're registering, the body of code that has the executable bits.
Service: This is the interface, or the way that the component exposes its executable bits.

So when you register things in pretty much any DI framework in .NET, you'll see a rough pattern of "register component X and expose it as service A."
In the "pure DI" example, you - the human - are making a choice to say "I want to expose ConcretePlugin as two different services: as itself and as IPlugin. The type system allows that to happen, but the programmatic consideration of what services you expose and how was made (intentionally or unintentionally) by you.
The reason it seems "dead simple" is because you're mentally skipping over the creation of the component-to-service mapping because that's inherent in the type system.
So why don't DI frameworks just "skip over that" as well, and let every component be exposed as every service? That's probably a better question, and I think it's a combination of:

Performance: If I have a strict map of component-to-service, I can do very fast lookups to see which components I have that can be injected into the dependencies of other components. If I need consider that component to be able to expose every service it could possibly expose (interfaces, base classes, etc.) then I'd need to build a cache of every possible thing it could fulfill (probably pretty sizable in a large system) and look that up for every parameter and property I inject, every time.
Brownfield projects: I may not actually own the code I'm working in, or may (due to various restrictions) not be allowed to change it. But I don't want component X to be injected as a service A ever. Yeah, it may implement that interface, and I may need to inject it, but I don't want it exposed using that interface for whatever reason.
Predictability: Generally the order of registration is the order in which the services will be picked to fill in dependencies. If the underlying code changes, that may have unpredictable effects on which component gets chosen to satisfy a dependency.

Let's walk that latter one through an example. Say you have this:
// This is PSEUDOCODE. It's in Autofac-ish style, but
// we're pretending that registering a type will also
// expose it as all of its interfaces by default. That's
// not how Autofac works.
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// A class `First` that implements the `IFirst` interface.
builder.RegisterType<First>();

// A class `Second` that implements the `ISecond` interface.
builder.RegisterType<Second>();

// A class that takes, as dependencies, `IFirst` and `ISecond`.
builder.RegisterType<ConsumesIFirstAndISecond>();

Now let's say this is a pretty large project. At some point, someone makes the choice to add the IFirst interface to the class Second. You know what happens now? The ConsumesIFirstAndISecond will get two copies of the class Second.
That's not an impossible-to-debug issue, but if you're working in a project with a team of folks of varying skill levels, it can be a non-zero-time thing to figure out. (At which point you'll possibly file an issue or raise a StackOverflow question asking why DI frameworks don't allow you to expressly specify the service during registration because that would have saved you a ton of time and this seems like a dead simple thing to allow).
Anyway, you see where I'm going there. DI isn't a type system. I think the analogy of "here's what no-DI vs. DI can do in a two line example" is maybe oversimplifying the issue. I mean, if what you want is the no-DI behavior, then... just use no DI, right?
But all that said, I did say I'd show you how Autofac can do this.
There are two things that Autofac has that you should be aware of:

AsSelf() - this exposes a class as itself and is the default unless other services are explicitly specified.
AsImplementedInterfaces() - this is basically the helper method that other answers have mentioned you might have to write. It goes through and registers a given thing as all of its interfaces.
ContravariantRegistrationSource - this basically "opts you in" to allowing you to resolve types in a contravariant context. It's not helpful in this specific example, but since you're interested in a similar area here, I figured I'd include it.

For what you want, AsSelf() and AsImplementedInterfaces() are the key.
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
  .RegisterInstance(new ConcretePlugin(/*some arguments here*/))
  .AsSelf()
  .AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<TestConcrete>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<TestList>().SingleInstance();
var container = builder.Build();

// These will work.
container.Resolve<TestConcrete>();
container.Resolve<TestList>();

Anyway, I hope that all helps clarify a little. Whether it's satisfying or not is another question, but maybe at least it explains it a bit.

No I'm sorry, I beg to differ. In DI, there are neither "Services" nor "Components". There are objects that need to be composed. And that's the primary thing I would expect from a DI framework. Anyway, thanks for your time to write the answer but I ended up using pure DI. The framework helped me to prototype. Then I removed it and I was all set.
